# How to set LARGEADRESSAWARE for a ClickOnce app?

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I've been wrestling with this for a while now. I have an app that uses a lot of mem and really would benefit from being *LargeAddressAware*.

**Problem in short: With the LAA-flag, the app won't start.**

Empirical results:

1) I have a release script that runs the entire ClickOnce publishing, then re-signs the executables and dlls, then re-creates the manifest, signs it etc

2) Running the script gives me an app that installs and works nicely

3) Adding this to the post-build breaks the app:

```
editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE <path>/obj/Publish/app.exe
```

(yes, I know, we have a build config that's called *Publish* - idiotic - but works...)

The error message I get is:

*Activation of \betabox\appbeta\app.application resulted in exception.*
*Following failure messages were detected:*

*+ Strong name signature not valid for this assembly app.exe.*

Both my the manifest and the exe is signed by a valid code signing cert. And the script works fine when the flag does not get set.

I've tried without my script as well, with just the *editbin* command in the post-build and publishing through VS - same error.

So - is it totally impossible to publish an app with LARGEADRESSAWARE set through ClickOnce?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved!

Got help from Kira in the ClickOnce forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/b008087c-45f8-4de6-b8f5-f34fddb29c8c/?prof=required

**Solution:** 
The EXE has to be re-signed with a new strong name after the LAA flag has been set.

**How to do this:**
In the post-build, the flag is set by:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE obj/$(ConfigurationName)/app.exe
```

And after that, also in the post-build, the exe has to be re-signed:

```
sn -Ra obj\$(ConfigurationName)\app.exe PublicPrivateKeyFile.snk
```

This is of course assuming that the PublicPrivateKeyFile.snk is a code signing key and in the path of the Visual Studio project.

My problem was that I was re-signing all dlls/exes after the build using:

```
for /R %BIN_DIR% %%f in (*.dll) do signtool sign /a /i "Thawte" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "%%f"
for /R %BIN_DIR% %%f in (*.exe) do signtool sign /a /i "Thawte" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "%%f"
```

But this does not update the strong name, just signs the exe as it is.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot trying to figure out why my `editbin` change wasn't getting applied when doing a ClickOnce deploy.  I did not realize that ClickOnce publishes using the files in the **obj** folder, and does NOT use the **bin** output folder.